# Do all pdf pages have to have the same height?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

Can I generate a pdf with different page heights? e.g. normally all pages would be A4 and between 2 pages I want to insert a page that is only half the size?

Comment: Yes, the pdf specification does support that, although the finer details are down to your generator.

Comment: @Bathsheba Please make that an answer the OP can accept.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly each page of your document can be described independently, and as a result, each page can be a completely different size or orientation. It doesn't matter whether you're generating them on the fly or bringing in an existing page of a different size from its neighbors.

Each page carries its own page information, including height and width (MediaBox, CropBox, etc.), rotation and other attributes that can be tied to that one page.

You might want to take a look at Section 3.6 of the PDF Reference ("Document Structure"), and (in particular) the section there on Inheritance of Page Attributes (page 149 of the old Sixth Edition I have here), which goes into useful detail about how a page can inherit the attributes of the previous page, or declare its own instead.